# How much dry ground ginger do I substitute for fresh grated ginger?

Tags: substitutions

I don't use ginger enough to really justify getting it fresh, so how much of dried ground ginger should I use in recipes that call for fresh grated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fresh ginger and dried ginger are very different, the flavour, texture and properties are not overly similar that they can not readily be substituted for each other.

Having said that, in the instances where they can be substituted I have seen estimated from 8:1 up to 6:1 (fresh:dried).

Comment: `s/can readily/can not readily/`?

Comment: @dmckee: Corrected by a sed/perl sub, and they say that the other stack exchange sites are only populated by the SO overflow, cheers. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you have room in your freezer, you can peel and freeze ginger whole and then grate it frozen into a dish.

Comment: You can also grate the ginger first, freeze it on waxed paper on a cookie sheet, then bag it all up in a plastic bag kept in the freezer.

Comment: For savoury uses, I buy a "cheat" ingredient when it comes to "fresh" ginger. Very Lazy Ginger, pre-chopped and preserved in a very mild white wine vinegar that pretty much evaporates on heating.  I just do not use enough to keep on standby fresh and prefer it to frozen. http://www.verylazy.com/chopped-ingredients/2009/8/12/very-lazy-ginger-190g.html

Comment: @Doug - I don't know why that never occurred to me (especially since I dice or strip my onions and peppers, freeze flat, then bag), I'm going to try that next time, thanks!